# Kohana ORM multiple relationships in models

Tags: php, orm, model, kohana

I'm new to this and working with a module in Gallery3 that has been abandoned and looking to add some functionality.  I've searched all over and haven't been able to find a solution.

I have the following tables.

```
Products {id, name, description, cost, discount_id, postage_id)
Discounts {id, name, threshold, amount, maxamount)
Postage_bands {id, name, flatrate, peritem)
```

I added the discounts to offer customers a discount based on amount spent.  I based it on the existing Postage table and copied the associated pages so they work with the new Discount functionality.  I want the admin page for the products to list which Discount and postage is associated with each product.

The admin pages for the Discounts work just fine.

What I am having problems with is the relationship between Products to Discounts and Postage.  I can only get one or the other working.

There are the models, each in their own file.

```
class Product_Model extends ORM {
  var $rules = array(
    "name" => "length[1,32]",
    "description" => "length[0,255]");
    protected $belongs_to=array('discount');
    protected $belongs_to=array('postage_band');
}

class Postage_Band_Model extends ORM {
    var $rules = array(
    "name" => "length[1,32]");
    protected $has_many=array('products');
}

class Discount_Model extends ORM {
    var $rules = array(
    "name" => "length[1,32]");
    protected $has_many=array('products');
}
```

The code in the views page that displays information relating to the Discount or Postage is

```
<?= html::clean($product->discount->name) ?>
or
<?= html::clean($product->postage_band->name) ?>
```

I can only get one or the other working by commenting out wither the Discount or Postage lines from the Products_model and the code to display it in the views page.

How can I get relationships of columns in one table to work with columns in two separate tables. In this case

- Products.discount_id to Discounts.id, so I can point to the name field in the Discounts table.
- Products.postage_id to Postage_bands.id, so I can point to the name field in the Postage_bands table.

or any other fields in those table if I need them.

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: Dont forget to accept correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring $belongs_to twice. Try:

```
class Product_Model extends ORM {

    protected $belongs_to=array('discount', 'postage_band');
}
```

Also, I think it's $_belongs_to

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  As for the "$_belongs_to" vs "$belongs_to", I'm not sure why, but Gallery 3 doesn't use the proceeding _.  When looking for the answer, I saw lots of posts where the _ was used and tried it, but didn't work at all.